# Parsing dates with parse_date_time: Why does "2004-04-04 02:00" fail?

Tags: r, lubridate

I am parsing dates with `lubridate::parse_date_time` and some dates just don't work. For example, why does `2004-04-04 02:00` return `NA` but `2004-04-04 01:00` and `2004-04-04 03:00` work?

```
library("lubridate")
"2004-04-04 01:00" %>% parse_date_time(c("Ymd HM"), tz = "America/New_York")
"2004-04-04 02:00" %>% parse_date_time(c("Ymd HM"), tz = "America/New_York")
"2004-04-04 03:00" %>% parse_date_time(c("Ymd HM"), tz = "America/New_York")
```

Here are two other examples that return `NA`:

```
"20110313 0240" %>% parse_date_time(c("Ymd HM"), tz = "America/New_York")
"20130310 0255" %>% parse_date_time(c("Ymd HM"), tz = "America/New_York")
```

I am using lubridate version 1.6.0.

Comment: Daylight saving time change... goes directly from 1:59 to 3:00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was no `2004-04-04 02:00` in `America/New_York`.  After `2004-04-04 01:59:59 EST`, the clock ticked forward to `2004-04-04 03:00:00 EDT`, starting daylight saving time.

Your timestamps are likely stored in `EST5` rather than `America/New_York`.

```
> "2004-04-04 01:00" %>% parse_date_time(c("Ymd HM"), tz = "EST5") %>% with_tz("America/New_York")
[1] "2004-04-04 01:00:00 EST"
> "2004-04-04 02:00" %>% parse_date_time(c("Ymd HM"), tz = "EST5") %>% with_tz("America/New_York")
[1] "2004-04-04 03:00:00 EDT"
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there an easy way to check that and correct wrong values so that `2004-04-04 02:00` is recorded as `2004-04-04 03:00`?

Comment: I updated the answer with an example, parsing the timestamps using the EST5 timezone.